# $select on dynamic property

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have the following code:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Press Press { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class BooksController : ODataController
{
    private IList<Book> _books = new List<Book>
    {
        new Book
        {
            ISBN = "978-0-7356-7942-9",
            Title = "Microsoft Azure SQL Database Step by Step",

            Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"k1","v1"},
                {"k2","v2"}
            }
        },
        new Book
        {
            ISBN = "978-0-7356-8383-9",
            Title = "SignalR",
            Press = new Press
            {
                Name = "Microsoft Press",
                Category = Category.Book
            },
            Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"k1","v1"}
            }
        }
    };

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Book> Get()
    {
        return _books.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

When the $select is used on dynamic property, the result contains a lot of empty objects for those which don't contain the property. Let's say in this example if the query is `http://localhost:58020/Books?$select=K2`, I am getting the response as:

```
{
  @odata.context: "http://localhost:58020/$metadata#Books(k2)",
  value: [
   {
      k2: "v2"
   },
   { }
  ]
}
```

If you observe it contains an empty braces for a book which doesn't contain the property `k2`. How to get rid of this behavior?.

Answer (score 0):

Thats an issue of Dictionary. What you can do is create a new class named `Parameter` and instead of using `Dictionary<String, object>`, use `List<Parameter>` like the following:

```
class Parameter {
    public String Key;
    public Object Value;
}
```

Modified Code:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Press Press { get; set; }
    public List<Parameter> Properties { get; set; }
}
public class BooksController : ODataController
{
    private IList<Book> _books = new List<Book>
    {
        new Book
        {
            ISBN = "978-0-7356-7942-9",
            Title = "Microsoft Azure SQL Database Step by Step",

            Properties = new List<Parameter>
            {
                new Parameter { Key = "k1", Value = "v1" },
                new Parameter { Key = "k2", Value = "v2" }
            }
        },
        new Book
        {
            ISBN = "978-0-7356-8383-9",
            Title = "SignalR",
            Press = new Press
            {
                Name = "Microsoft Press",
                Category = Category.Book
            },
            Properties = new List<Parameter>
            {
                new Parameter { Key = "k1", Value = "v1" }
            }
        }
    };

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Book> Get()
    {
        return _books.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Waseem, thanks for the attempt but this won't work. The reason for having dictionary is to support open type. The key and the respective value in the dictionary will be rendered as such like a declared property of Book in the get call. Converting it to list is not a suitable approach. you may want to have a look at this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/use-open-types-in-odata-v4)